# DOMDocument access tag content

Tags: php, domdocument

```
<title>foo</title>
<meta name='description' content='foo' />

$url = 'http://www.google.com';

//CURL
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$site = curl_exec($ch);

//DOM
$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($site);

$title=$dom->getElementsByTagName('title');
$description=$dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');

echo $title-> ;//need to access object
echo $ele-> tagDescription; //need access tag description
```

I have a page try to use DOMDocument to scrape page title, description, og:image etc. from url.

I don't know how to access objects; does anyone know how to solve this?

What if there is more than one element? Do I need to convert them into an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName('meta');
foreach($links as $link){
    $name = $link->getAttribute('name');

    if($name == 'description'){$description = $link->getAttribute('content');}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XPath` for that:

```
$selector = new DOMXPath($dom);
$node = $selector->query('//meta[@name="description"]/@content')->item(0);
$description = $node->nodeValue;
```

With XPath you can select the `<meta name="description" ...>` node directly and you don't need a foreach loop over all `<meta>` nodes